# How to make a kick command in python for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a moderation bot for discord and want to add a kick command.
I did some research on kick commands but none of them work.
The error is:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "kick" is not found
```

Here's my code:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await client.kick(member)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kick')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like `client.kick(member)`. I think you are trying to do [`member.kick()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.kick). Here is an example of kick command:

```py
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has kicked.')
```

Comment: I get a error: Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "kick" is not found

Comment: Are you restarting your bot?